# Component vert.x does not propagate headers

Tags: apache-camel, vert.x

I'm using the Camel component Vertx: http://camel.apache.org/vertx.html

The headers set in Camel are not sent into the eventBus address:

```
from("direct:inbound")
  .setHeader("myHeader").constant("myHeaderValue")
  .to("vertx:inboundAddress");
```

inboundAddress does not receive the header "myHeader".

I've checked the code of the VertxProducer in Vertx Component and it actually only send the body.Is there any reason why the headers are not sent to the eventBus?

Btw, the documentation on GitHub is much more up to date: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-vertx/src/main/docs/vertx-component.adoc

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the vertx headers should be accessible via camel.  If someone sees an official way it is supported I would love to know.  Until then there is an easy workaround though.  Instead of passing just the body in the message pass both the headers and the body as the message body and both will be accessible.

```
    JsonObject message = new JsonObject();
    message.put("body", routingContext.getBodyAsJson());
    DeliveryOptions d = new DeliveryOptions()
       .addHeader("myheader", "myheadervalue")
       .addHeader("h2", "h2value");
    message.put("deliveryOptions", d.toJson());

    vertx.eventBus().send("myVertxEndpoint",
                message,...
```

Later in Camel, you could call a method similar to the following as part of your route to have the Vertx headers put inside the camel headers.

```
    public void setVertxHeaders(@Body JsonObject jsonObject, Exchange exchange ) {       
      exchange.getIn().getHeaders()
       .putAll(jsonObject.getJsonObject("deliveryOptions").getJsonObject("headers")
       .getMap());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the headers incorrectly.
Instead of

```
.setHeader("myHeader").constant("myHeaderValue")
```

Do

```
.setHeader("myHeader", constant("myHeaderValue"))
```

See their test suite for more references:
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/3505e718db48cc0d8be5b47f6c4030c958d93a5f/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/bean/BeanWithAnnotationInheritedTest.java

Comment: Thank you for your answer Alexey.
Unfortunately, it does not change anything. The problem comes from the vertx component....